# Add Brand To Analytics.js Ecommerce's AddTransaction?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics.js

In Google's Analytics.js documentation (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce), they outline the following inputs for adding an item to a transaction:

```
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '{{transaction_id}} ',
    'name': '{{ name }}',
    'sku': '{{sku}} ',
    'category':'{{category}}',
    'price': '{{ price }}',
    'currency':'{{ currency }}',
    'quantity': '{{ quantity }}'
  });
```

Is it possible to add a 'brand' value to this? You can add a brand value to other reports (e.g. impressions, see: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce) and was curious if anyone knew if this was possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `brand` associated with the product is a parameter of `Enhanced Ecommerce` so **you can't add it** to the code you entered because it is for `Standard Ecommerce`.